# sum of 2 gaussian variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I have a small problem, could you tell me what is wrong with my reasoning?

I have 2 gaussian variables $X$ and $Y$, with correlation $p$, clearly $X + Y$ is not gaussian because $X$ and $Y$ are not independant.

But if I use the Cholesky decomposition and set $Y = \sqrt(p)X + \displaystyle \sqrt(1-p)U$ with $X$ and $U$ independant and gaussian, we have that $X + Y = (1 + \sqrt(p)X + \sqrt(1-p)U$ which is gaussian.

What is my mistake here?

Comment: As is common in math, the mistake is immediately after the word "clearly"

Comment: The sum is a random variable, so saying that it's "independent" doesn't really make a whole lot of sense.  The sum can be *Gaussian*, for instance if $(X,Y)$ is jointly Gaussian.

Comment: Yes I meant "The sum might be gaussian even if $X$ and $Y$ are not independant"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of mistakes here: first of all, $X + Y$ may be Gaussian, even if they are not independent; as an example, let $W$ and $Z$ be independent and Gaussian, and set $X = W + Z$ and $Y = W$.  Then $X$ and $Y$ aren't independent, but $X + Y = 2W + Z$, which is Gaussian since $2W$ and $Z$ are independent and Gaussian.  More generally, if $(X,Y)$ is jointly Gaussian, then $X + Y$ is Gaussian (this need not go in the reverse manner).

The Cholesky decomposition that you're written down **only works if $(X,Y)$ is jointly Gaussian.**  As an example, consider taking $X$ and $W$ to be independent standard normals and set $Y = \mathrm{sgn}(X) W$.